# Transform XML to Filemaker XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, filemaker

I am finding it very hard indeed to learn XSLT - there seems to a lack of beginners guides that aren't already bewilderingly complex. I hope someone might help me, please.

I need to transform a simple XML file below into XML that can be read by Filemaker 12:

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <ref>12345</ref>
        <location>somewhere
        <price>12345</price>
        <photos>
            <photo>www.test.com/1.jpg</photo>
            <photo>www.test.com/2.jpg</photo>
            <photo>www.test.com/3.jpg</photo>
        </photos>
        <details>
            <summary>nice house</summary>
            <description>a very very nice house</description>
        </details>
    </property>
</properties>
```

I cannot seem to work out how to loop through the photos (which may be 1 or 30 in number) and also get the summary and description.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks!

This is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
    <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
    <PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 12.0v4"/>
    <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT=""/>
    <METADATA>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ref" TYPE="TEXT" />
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="location" TYPE="TEXT" />
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="price" TYPE="NUMBER" />
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="30" NAME="photo" TYPE="TEXT" />
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="summary" TYPE="TEXT" />
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="description" TYPE="TEXT" />
    </METADATA>
    <RESULTSET FOUND="">
    <xsl:for-each select="properties/property">
        <ROW RECORDID="" MODID="">
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="ref"/></DATA></COL>
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="location"/></DATA></COL>
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="price"/></DATA></COL>
            <xsl:for-each select="properties/property/photos">
            <COL>
                <DATA><xsl:value-of select="photo"/></DATA>
            </COL>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="summary"/></DATA></COL>
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="description"/></DATA></COL>
        </ROW>
    </xsl:for-each>     
    </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
      <xsl:for-each select="properties/property/photos">
        <COL>
            <DATA><xsl:value-of select="photo"/></DATA>
        </COL>
```

you probably want

```
      <xsl:for-each select="photos/photo">
        <COL>
            <DATA><xsl:value-of select="."/></DATA>
        </COL>
```

At that point the current node is the `property` element which is why

```
        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="price"/></DATA></COL>
```

on the line above worked, so your `properties/property/photos` path is looking for a `properties` element child of `properties` which is not there.

Comment: Hi there - thanks very much. This has worked, but it only shows one of the photos on the output to Filemaker. What I want is to have all of the photos, preferably numbered if possible: photo1, photo2, photo3, etc - any ideas. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: If your input is as described  `<xsl:for-each select="photos/photo">`  will make a `<COL` entry for each photo. You never said what you wanted the output XMl to be. Perhaps you want want COL element with one DATA for each photo? or ????

Comment: Hi David - I've actually sorted this out and thanks for your help once again. In the Filemaker section of the XSL where the fields are defined, I added fields for photo1, photo2, photo3, etc and now it works.